# how to How to recognize that a number is between two strings ؟

Tags: python

i want to recognize that a number is between two strings and return False:

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")


def is_valid(s):
    while True:
        len_plate = len(s)
        if 2 <= len_plate <= 6:
            if s[0] == '0':
                return False   
            else:
                for plt in s:
                    if plt.isupper():
                        return False
                    else:
                        return True            
            return False

main()
```

i want to add to this program, if a number is between two strings it should return false, and just because input is string, i don't know how to do it, actually no problem if number is exist at the end, but if after the number is a string it should return False

### for example cla34 is True, and cla4s is False

thankyou

Comment: What do you mean with "if a number is between two strings"? Can you provide an input with an expected output?

Comment: for example faa22 is ok, but fas23f is not

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to add examples of both valid and invalid `plate` values that cover your use cases.

Comment: regex : `(\w+\d+[^\w])`

Comment: What about: `cla` (no number at all) or `34` (just a number)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to achieve this. One regex to check if there are numbers between two substrings would be `^\D+(\d+)\D+$`.

**Some examples:**

```
Input: "asd123asd" (Valid)

Input: "asdasdasd" (Invalid)
Input: "asd123" (Invalid)
Input: "123asd123" (Invalid)
Input: "asd123asd123" (Invalid)
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/DeyuDb/1

---

You can then use this regular expression with [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in python.

```py
import re


def are_numbers_between(s):
    pattern = re.compile(r"^\D+(\d+)\D+$")
    if pattern.match(s): return True

    return False


plate = input("Plate: ")
print("Valid") if are_numbers_between(plate) is True else print("Invalid")
```